# autoenv executes even in subfolder

Tags: python, virtualenv

I uses [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) for automatic `virtualenv` activate. Python project's top folder has `.env` file with following contents

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

This command executed whenever `cd` to any sub folder of the project. Then throws

```
-bash: venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

It failed because it is trying to execute `activate` relative to sub folder. Why it executes even in subfolder? How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had this issue today. The current answer doesn't address the fact that the environment is activated every time you `cd` into a subfolder or back to the root folder. Solved it with the following `.env` script:

```
venv=venv
currentvenv=""

if [[ $VIRTUAL_ENV != "" ]]
then
  # Strip out the path and just leave the env name
  currentvenv="${VIRTUAL_ENV##*/}"
fi

if [[ "$currentvenv" != "$venv" ]]
then
  echo "Switching to environment: $venv"
  workon $venv
#else
#  echo "Already on environment $venv"
fi
```

Replace `venv` with the name of your environment. You can uncomment the else block to see that it doesn't try to activate the environment every time, given that the desired environment is already activated.

Note: If you're not using `virtualenvwrapper` then you should replace the `workon` command with whatever command you're using to activate your virtual environment. I do recommend using `virtualenvwrapper` though.

Answer (score 0):

In your workspace root, a `.env` containing:

```
test (command -v deactivate) && deactivate
```

and in each of your relevant project folders:

```
workon venv_of_project
```

As [this person points out,](https://www.kormoc.com/2014/03/22/autoenv-and-virtualenv/) it means that `cd`ing around in a project will turn the workspace on and off, but at least it is simple and very clear what is going on.