# How do I call workon only once when entering a autoenv-ed directory?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Autoenv is super! But, my terminal has gotten a bit slower because autoenv calls workon  every time I cd from one directory to another beneath the autoenv root. How can I customize my .env file so that workon  is only called when I initially enter the directory?

Answer (score 2):

I have this in my *.env* file:

```
type deactivate &>/dev/null || source venv/bin/activate
```

Check if the environment is activated. If not, activate the environment otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple projects, each with its own virtualenv, and you want to switch automatically between virtualenvs when you `cd` into the project folders (and of course make sure `workon` is only called when necessary) then you'll need some more logic in your `.env` file:

```
venv=venv
currentvenv=""

if [[ $VIRTUAL_ENV != "" ]]
then
  # Strip out the path and just leave the env name
  currentvenv="${VIRTUAL_ENV##*/}"
fi

if [[ "$currentvenv" != "$venv" ]]
then
  echo "Switching to environment: $venv"
  workon $venv
#else
#  echo "Already on environment $venv"
fi
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27987379/2915101